# Reading and halving a sas data set

Tags: sas

I have to read a data set of 50 numbers from a text file. It's all in a row with a space delimiter and in multiple uneven lines. for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6

7 8 9 10 11 12

13 14 15 

16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Etc.

The first 25 numbers belong to group 1, and the 2nd 25 belong to group 2. So I need to make a group variable (binary either 1 or 2), a count number (1 to 25), and a value variable which is holding the value of the number.

I am stuck on how to split the data in half when reading it. I tried to use truncover but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, replacing the `datalines` keyword with the path to your file:

```
data groups;
  infile datalines;
  format number 8. counter 2. group 1.; * Not mandatory, used here to order variables;
  retain group (1);
  input number @@;
  counter + 1;
  if counter = 26 then do;
    group = 2;
    counter = 1;
  end;
  datalines;
192 105 435 448 160 499 184 246 388 190 316 
139 146 147 192 231 449 101 216 342 399 352 122 418
280 400 187 352 321 180 425 500 320 179 105 
232 105 323 132 106 255 449 
186 135 472 174 119 255
308 350
run;
```

Comment: You could just use \_n_ as the counter here, or use it to set the group value `group=(_n_>25)+1`

Comment: fair comment, it all depends on how important the counter variable is (i.e. is it just there to determine group).  You could always set counter to `mod(_n_-1,25)+1`